# How to select multiple tables in single query mysql? (some tables have no data yet)

Tags: mysql, database, select, relational-database, database-table

I have 3 tables called `patients`, `customers` and `deliveries`. Those tables are in the same database called `db`.

All the tables equally have `id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `gender` and only `deliveries` table has their own data. (the other 2 tables are currently empty.)

Now, I want to select all of them in 1 query but mysql throws an error this:

> SELECT first_name, last_name, gender FROM paitents, customers,
>   deliveries GROUP BY people LIMIT 0, 50000 Error Code: 1052. Column
>   'first_name' in field list is ambiguous   0.047 sec .

This is how I tried:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, gender
FROM patients, customers, deliveries
GROUP BY people;
```

How do I select all of the tables even if some tables currently have no data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All the tables equally have id, first_name, last_name, gender and only deliveries table has their own data. (the other 2 tables are currently empty.)
>
> Now, I want to select all of them in 1 query

I suspect that you are looking for `union all`:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, gender FROM patients
UNION ALL
SELECT first_name, last_name, gender FROM customers 
UNION ALL 
SELECT first_name, last_name, gender FROM deliveries
```

This will combine all records available in the 3 tables in the resultset. On the other hand, using an (implicit) `cross join` like you do would generate a cartesian product of the 3 tables, with 9 columns (3 * 3) in the resultset (that is, if you fix the ambiguity on column names that you currently have).

If you want to eliminate duplicates accross tables, you can use `union` instead of `union all`.

If you want to limit the number of records in the resultset, you can do this as follows:

```
(
    SELECT first_name, last_name, gender FROM patients
    UNION ALL
    SELECT first_name, last_name, gender FROM customers 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT first_name, last_name, gender FROM deliveries
)
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 5000
```

Note that, functionaly this does require an `order by` clause, otherwise the ordering of the results is undefined (I assumed `id`).

Comment: Thanks for giving detailed answer. Helps a lot.